# Adding new permissions resulted in: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I made an app where the user logs in to their Office 365 account and I perform actions using the Microsoft Graph API. When I first started the app, I requested for little permissions such as profile and mail permissions. However, I now want to access the user's calendar and thus I added more permissions (Calendars.Read, Calendars.ReadWrite).

Now, when I try to get the user's calendar events, I receive the following error:

> {code: ErrorAccessDenied, message: Access is denied. Check credentials
>   and try again., innerError: {request-id:
>   33074527-630e-41cf-bd00-4fcd5f0ac816, date: 2018-09-10T03:15:07}}

I noticed that once I added these calendar permissions, it didn't prompt the user to accept these new permissions so I think that's why I don't have access. Do I have to delete my app or something in order to get these permissions from the user? I tried to force the user to sign in again adding new permission requests to the `scopes` variable but it still didn't ask the user for these permissions.

Comment: Did you add the scopes in your requests? And did you add the permissions in your Application management

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to update the consent recorded for the user. My guess is you are using the [Azure v1 OAUth2 endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code), as this problem tends to crop up there more often than the v2 endpoints :).

The problem here is that the first time your user consented, Azure recorded their consent so they wouldn't be prompted again. That record captured the permissions you initially had configured on your app registration. Azure v1 is not "smart" enough to detect that you've added new permissions on your app registration since the user's consent was recorded, so it happily continues to issue tokens with the old permissions, skipping the user prompt.

To get the prompt to show up, you need to include a `prompt=consent` query parameter on the authorization URL, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code).

If you're using the [v2 OAuth2 endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview), this becomes a bit easier. With the v2 endpoints, all you have to do is include the new permission scopes in the `scope` query parameter for your authorization URL. Azure will detect that the user hasn't consented for them, and will prompt.

So how do you tell which endpoint you're using?

- Did you register the app at https://portal.azure.com? You're using v1.
- Are you using ADAL libraries in your code? That's v1.
- Are you using MSAL libraries? That's v2.
- Does your code send the user to a URL that has `v2.0` in it? You guessed it, that's v2. If there's no `v2.0` in it, it's v1.